# How to avoid being charged for public calls to Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After studying the documentation, I've observed the following about Realtime Database:

> We can use any Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint. All we need to do is append .json to the end of the URL and send a request from our favorite HTTPS client.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)

> All traffic to and from your database, including operations denied by security rules, leads to billable costs.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing)

This could be a huge problem since,

- Anyone on the internet can send requests to our database URL.
- Even if those requests were denied using security rules, we would still be charged for them.
- A malicious user could theoretically keep calling the endpoint until they exhaust our resources.

I did think of a few workarounds like:

- Caching/Proxying requests using something like Cloudflare. Works great... until someone gets their hands on the origin database URL and attacks that directly.
- Restricting origin database access to a secure code environment using Cloud IAM or domain constraints. This is something you get with most GCP offerings but not FirebaseRealtime Database AFAIK.

Are there any other ways to protect a database from public requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you're supposed to require that the end user be authenticated using Firebase Authentication, then implement [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) that define who is allowed to read and write which nodes in the database.  The REST API allows for [passing authentication credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) in the request.

If you're not using Firebase Auth, and instead providing direct access to your database from anyone on the internet, you should probably **not** allow direct access to the database with the provided endpoint.  Security rules should be configured to disallow all unauthenticated access, and you should require all access through an API endpoint that performs only queries that you want to allow.  You will have to build this API yourself in order to protect the database from abusive queries.

Comment: **1) Suppose we do use Firebase Auth**. If a malicious user made requests (with invalid credentials) to the REST API. The request would be denied as expected, but **do we get billed for those bad requests?**... **2) Suppose we do not use Firebase Auth**. We use custom API authentication and have proper database security rules. If a malicious user made invalid requests directly to the database's REST API, **we get billed even though the operation was denied, correct?**... So my question is, **is there any way to avoid getting billed for bad requests to the database's REST API?**

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. Unless your rules have to read other data to ensure the request is denied.

Comment: Oh... so as long as we authenticate users directly (or using custom tokens), we don't have to worry about direct REST API requests. However, **rule validation** is still billed...... Alright, that's good enough for us! Thank you :)